# handler not working while executing playbook using ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

This is my task file:

```
- name: installing epel-release
  yum:
   name: epel-release
   state: installed

- name: installing required packages
  yum:
   name: "{{ item }}"
   state: installed
  with_items:
    - nrpe
    - nagios-plugins-all
    - openssl

- name: pushing nrpe.cfg
  template:
      src: nrpe.cfg.j2
      dest: /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
      backup: yes
  notify: restart nrpe
```

While executing this playbook.Everything is running fine.Eventhough handler is executing nrpe is not started when i checked my client server.

This is my handler file

```
- name: restart nrpe
  service:
     name: nrpe
     state: restarted
     enabled: yes
```

Comment: Did "pushing nrpe.cfg"  have a changed state?  Also include the output of your playbook run.

Comment: yeah it is changed.But service not started

Comment: Look at its status manually with `systemctl status nrpe` or whatever init system you have.   Check any log files the service has for if it attempted to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a service to your playbook, enable and start it there. The handler is just for restarts when the file changes, and I think it won't start it when its not running...

Comment: @lazyfrosch..Thanks for the information.Iam not sure handler will start a service without placing it in main playbook.(Iam a begginer to ansible)..If iam starting service in main playbook everything is fine.